# Visual Studio set command arguments

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging, command

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Now, I have a few C# and C++ projects in a solution. Under project properties I can add some debugging properties. That works fine. But when I run the visual studio solution on another computer the command arguments are deleted.

How can I define default command arguments that are also available when I run the project on another computer?

Comment: Have you checked that the properties are being saved? Project properties should stay with the project once they are saved. If you close and re-open the solution on the same computer are the properties still there? Are you running the  same project within the solution (and in debug mode) on the other computer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, if I reopen the same project everything is there but if I pull the project from git in a new folder the config is not available anymore, in which file does the parameters get stored?

Comment: Some project properties are stored in PROJECTNAME.csproj.user files. I thought they were all in the .csproj file but it seems some are in .csproj.user (I just checked with the "Debug-Command line arguments property"). This file is probably being ignored by git. I'm not sure how to get all the properties to be saved to the .csproj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using other computer for debugging, then instead of setting the arguments in properties, set them via `config` file.

let's say following is your config file (by-default it is `App.config`),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
<add key ="key1" value ="Sample" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To get value of `key1` use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];`. You can add multiple keys in `<appSettings>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How does it work with the config file?

Comment: In config file set all the variables and read them using `ConfigurationManager`. Edited answer with an example

Comment: Thank you, does this also works within C++ projects?

Comment: Yes, if you can find a way to read `app.config`. BTW, you can mark it as answer, if your question is answered.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to know where they were, and you indirectly helped me to find them in properties for the project I'm compiling.

Answer (score 2):

Those command line arguments from Visual Studio are for debugging purposes only, so you have two options:

1) instruct your users to run your application with arguments from cmd (or provide a script to run your application)

or

2) code your application to accept some missing arguments, so that when no arguments are passed to execute as if the default arguments are passed.

Comment: With script I think you mean a batch file or somethink like that?

Comment: It can be batch or python or whatever you want it to be, batch has the advantage that it is running on windows without installing anything.